# Sending a Silent SMS

Tags: android, sms

How would one go about sending a silent sms (SMS class 0)? Preferably from an android device, but any input would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK is a class 0 a instantly shown sms, but you can send a silent (user doesn't recognize that an sms is sent) sms via SmsManager

See here: [SmsManager reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html)